# Cannot Move Files to Hard Drive/Not Enough Room on Destination File System- External HDD with Plenty of Space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, copy-paste

I have a working WD 4TB Hard Drive which was recently removed from a NAS. I performed a DOD (0x000) overwrite with a NTFS format, using the disk utility DiskWipe.exe - a free disk cleaning utility, and have placed it into an external storage enclosure to archive some data.

This gave me a full, empty 4TB drive formatted with NTFS and appeared just like any new hard drive should - both with confirmed logical and physical disk sectors.

So here is the problem:

I have been receiving errors that I cannot copy anymore information to the disk due "The file 'x' is too large for the destination file system.

This is quite strange - the first 2 TB copied fine (many files above 4GB threshold)... and there is 1.63 TB Left.

`fsutil fsinfo volumeinfo` as well as the built-in windows properties and disk management screens both list a properly formatted 4TB NTFS drive with 3.63 Logical TB available.

I have tried moving the drive to another computer, which is able to be read from just fine, but that doesn't help.

Just tried to copy a whopping 100kb file, and this even says it cant happen.

Further food for thought:  the exact used space on the drive right now is *exactly* 2.00TB, (2,203,470,118,912 bytes), and when it was in use on the NAS, it was confirmed to hold up to the logicial 3.63 TB.

(I have tried to also run a chkdsk but this command will not run due to WinErrors of "The shadow copy of volume G: could not create shadow copy storage on volume G: - in theory because it still thinks its out of space??)

Anyone have a solution?

```
vssadmin list shadowstorage:

**Shadow Copy Storage association
   For volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{f9b651b8-76af-47eb-b87f-b3249a2dbda0}\
   Shadow Copy Storage volume: (C:)\\?\Volume{f9b651b8-76af-47eb-b87f-b3249a2dbda0}\
   Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 6.97 GB (0%)
   Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 7.36 GB (0%)
   Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 18.6 GB (2%)**
```

Comment: Examine the disk for any large folders, especially ones marked as hidden or system. Post the results of in an elevated cmd entering `vssadmin list shadowstorage`. You might disable Volume Shadow Copy on the disk ([link](https://kb.datto.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554735-Disabling-and-purging-Shadow-Copies-on-Windows-Servers)). Which utility did you use for DOD?

Comment: @harrymc Have updated question as requested - I have also verified that there are no large hidden files or folders.  I used multiple tools to verify this and even WizTree (which can outline different file sizes) confirms these results.

Comment: Strange - it seems that you don't have any shadow storage on G. I'm a bit doubtful about the formatting by DiskWipe, so could you please post the output of `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo G:` in an elevated cmd.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the help but I narrowed it down to 32-bit only external usb 2.0 controllers

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 4TB hard drive from the external hard drive and put it directly to the 64-bit Windows 10 PC.  The drive allowed for more data to be loaded.  After running some more tests, it has become apparent that there is a lack in ability for 32-bit controlled usb 2.0 controllers to not support larger than 2 TB drives.  Newer, non-outdated external SATA connectors support 2TB+ drives, however older connectors do not support 64-bit transferring.  Although the drive itself is logically formatted to support 4TB, the external enclosure itself will not support loading more data.